# Simple SAM needs conversion to anonymous object

Tags: kotlin

I have the following simple interface

```
interface A {
    fun move(s:Boolean): Int
}
```

I have the following class

```
class X{
    fun draw (x: A): String{
        return "A"
    }

    fun main() {
      val temp = A {
          s -> 100
      }
      val a = draw ( { x -> 100} )
    }
}
```

However both `temp` and `a` fail to be declared. `temp` complains and the suggested fix is to convert to an anonymous object as follows (which defeats the whole purpose of using a SAM?)

```
val temp = object : A {
        override fun move(s: Boolean): Int {
            return 100
        }
    }
```

`a` complains about a type mismatch. My question is why does this simple SAM fail? The method signature is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Kotlin only has SAM conversion for interfaces defined in Java.
For pure Kotlin code you're supposed to use a function type such as:

```
typealias A = (s: Boolean) -> Int
```

However, the syntax you expected will be supported in Kotlin 1.4 with interface defined as `fun interface`.
As announced here:
[What to Expect in Kotlin 1.4 and Beyond](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond/#language-features)
and tracked as [KT-7770](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770)

Comment: More than hinted. Implemented in Kotlin 1.4 milestones, with interface defined as `fun interface`: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond/#language-features and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770.

Comment: @Raman Thanks, comments are incorporated the into the answer.

Comment: I'd recommend OP sees whether they can remove the interface and just use the function type, directly without even a typealias if possible.  Function types are used throughout the stdlib and are more flexible, without tying you down to a single functional interface.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin 1.4 has support for SAM conversions for Kotlin interfaces, in addition to the Java interface SAM conversion available in previous versions. See:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond/#language-features

With 1.4, you do need to define your interface as a "functional" interface:

```
fun interface A {
    fun move(s:Boolean): Int
}
```